# Configuration and optimization ImageMagic and Tesseract

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract, tiff

We are using ImageMagic and tesseract to try to read information in documents, but we are not finding the right configuration and combination of both softwares to optimize the original scanned tif document, and apply tesseract to it to obtain the information.

First we use to scan the document in a scanner with a configuration of 300 dpi, and the tif document produces uses to have 170KB size.

Then we try to run a pre-process of the image with imagemagic before passiing it to tesseract 3.0.3, to produce a PDF with text document.

The first command we use is this one:

```
    convert page.tiff -respect-parenthesis  -compress LZW -density 300 
-bordercolor black -border 1 -fuzz 1% -trim +repage -fill white -draw 
"color 0,0 floodfill" -alpha off -shave 1x1 -bordercolor black -border 2 
-fill white -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" -alpha off -shave 0x1 -fuzz 1% 
-deskew 40 +repage  temp.tiff
```

And then we apply it to tesseract this way:

```
tesseract -l spa temp.tiff temp pdf
```

This produces a quite heavy pdf https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3CPIZ_TyzFXd2UtWldfajR4SVU but tesseract is not able to read data that are in cells, or in a table just under the header of the table if the background of the header is darker.

Then we have tried to use this command with convert:

```
convert page.tiff -compress LZW -fuzz 1% -trim -alpha off -shave 1x1 temp.tiff
```

And this produces a very light pdf document https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3CPIZ_TyzFXWFEwT3JucDBTVVU, but we are still having the same problems.

Could someone point us what way shall we follow to optimize the image to try to obtain information like the ones in the example? or guidelines to optimize images to improve the tesseract accuracy?

The type of documents we are trying to process are very different with different kind of font types and sizes

Answer (score -1):

If on a Unix-based system, you could try my script, textcleaner, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php